# How do I set the paredit comment line wrap length (or turn it off)

Tags: emacs, clojure, paredit

Paredit mode is chopping my comments when they get to be longer than 70 characters like so:

```
;; a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b
```

becomes:

```
;; a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b
;; a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b
```

I would like to know how to change that 70 to 120 and optionally turn it off entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That most certainly is auto-fill-mode at work. To change the column at which emacs will split the line you can use M-x set-fill-column. If you want to change it permanently you can do it in your clojure-mode hook, something like:

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda () (set-fill-column 120)))
```

On the other hand, if you want to turn it off something like:

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-fill-mode 0)))
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: (auto-fill-mode 0) doesn't work. Though putting (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (λ () (set-fill-column 0))) in init.el does the trick